# roslaunch command does not run when put in crontab

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am setting crontab to let my computer to launch certain ros package when it starts up or reboots.

here is the content I put in crontab -e,
@reboot bash -c '/home/user/launch.sh'

while the launch.sh file simply contains a single roslaunch command,
#!/bin/bash
roslaunch socket_server socket.launch

The above .sh file confirms running fine in terminal, but every time when the pc (re)boots, the roslaunch commmand doesn't run as expected; and I can't even find any records in the sys log file.

Can anybody with experience on cron + ros configuring help?

thanks
clark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33482/roslaunch-command-does-not-run-when-put-in-crontab/) by [clark](https://answers.ros.org/users/401/clark/) on ROS Answers with karma: 393 on 2012-05-07

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to set up the ROS environment in the shell script.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clark](https://answers.ros.org/users/401/clark/) on 2012-05-07**:
Thanks for the quick help. You are totally right. After adding "source /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash" into the sh script, it works now

**Comment by [clark](https://answers.ros.org/users/401/clark/) on 2012-05-07**:
plus two points for other users who might be interested. First, the @reboot command need to be keyed in via crontab -e rather than sudo crontab -e; Secondly, using !/bin/bash rather !/bin/sh inside the shell script, or else commands like source won't work

**Comment by [cordic45](https://answers.ros.org/users/146035/cordic45/) on 2023-04-22**:
I use crontab to execute "roscore" when the system is started, but crontab -e does not work, and sduo must be added to work normally.

startUp.bash

```
#!/bin/bash
source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash
roscore
```

sudo crontab -e

```
# m h  dom mon dow   commandi
# ┌───────────── minute (0 - 59)
# │ ┌───────────── hour (0 - 23)
# │ │ ┌───────────── day of month (1 - 31)
# │ │ │ ┌───────────── month (1 - 12)
# │ │ │ │ ┌───────────── day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday to Saturday;
# │ │ │ │ │                                       7 is also Sunday on some systems)
# │ │ │ │ │
# │ │ │ │ │
# * * * * *  command_to_execute

@reboot  bash /home/dodo/Desktop/startUp.bash >> /var/log/myjob.log 2>&1
```